# Can i encrypt data in realtime database on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

i have a realtime database on firebase , and i want to encrypt only single field.

I have no idea to encrypt my user data on firebase.

is that possible to do?

Comment: the cvv and card number should not be saved to your database, that is against security and illegal.
what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, Just send encrypted field while saving at firebase and at time of fetching data again decrypt the string.

You can refer below code

```
public class KeyStoreClass {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "Blowfish";
    private static final String MODE = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String IV = "abcdefgh";
    private static final String KEY = "MyKey";

    public String encrypt(String value) {

        if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
            return "";
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] values = new byte[0];
        try {
            values = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public String decrypt(String value) {

        if (value == null || value.isEmpty())
            return "";

        byte[] values = new byte[0];
        try {
            values = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            values = value.getBytes();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(values));
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }


}
```

To use it :

To Encrypt : `keystore.encrypt(item.getPhNo())`

To Decrypt : `keystore.decrypt(patientDetail);`

Comment: i call  ```keystore.encrypt(item.getSomething)``` when saving data?

Comment: Yes and save that on firebase

Comment: i getting error , bcs typedata required ```Long``` but found ```String```

Comment: pls post your code

Comment: this is our private code, can you share your telegram? i will contact you

Comment: i dont have telegram, just post snippet, if u can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200538/discussion-between-eminent-and-muhammad-faisal).

Comment: this is work for ```String``` data type , but how this can work with ```Long``` data type?

Comment: Convert long to string as appening String.valueOf(longdata)

Comment: check the discussion

Comment: i want to save with ```Long``` data type , but when i using ```helper.encrypt()``` ther result is a ```String``` data type